# SelectableText.rich in Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to use the following code snippet :

```
SelectableText.rich(
  TextSpan(
    text: 'Hello', // default text style
    children: <TextSpan>[
      TextSpan(text: ' beautiful ', style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic)),
      TextSpan(text: 'world', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
    ],
  ),
)
```

After exporting for the web I noticed that the text is not selectable. Is it by chance a feature not supported for the web but only on mobile?

Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Web is still at alpha preview level.  Check the flutter issues, and if you can't find it already marked as an issue, feel free.  It's fairly easy to get noticed, but you might not like the priority it gets perhaps. :)